# copy data from single column to multiple rows of specific columns in another sheet in excel

Tags: excel, vba

I have data in single column `Sheet1!A10:A122`.

I want to copy this data into multiple rows of another sheet `Sheet2!A14:G14` and `A15:G15` and `A16:G16` and so on until the last non blank cell in `Range(A10:A122)`.

How can I achieve this using vba?

Answer (score 0):

Try using a for loop

```
' Declare worksheets to variables
set ws = ThisWorkbook.Sheets(Sheet1)
set ws2 = ThisWorkbook.Sheets(Sheet2)
' Column Counter (A=1)
h = 1
' Start For loop between lower and upper bound of range (10 to 122)
For i = 10 to 122
    ' If the position of the column on Sheet2 has gone beyond G reset to A and move to next row
    if j > 7 then j = 1: h = h + 1
    ' Copy Data
    ws.cells(i,1) = ws2.cells(h, j)
    ' Move along one column
    j = j + 1
Next i
```

Comment: Thank You My Dear Friend for Your Valuable Effort

Answer (score 0):

I got the answer for my Question myself. Here it is

```
{
n = 10
For k = 14 To Sheets("Sheet1").Range("A10:A"&Rows.Count).SpecialCells(xlCellTypeBlanks).Row
    For m = 1 To 7
        Sheets("Sheet2").Cells(k, m) = Sheets("Sheet1").Cells(n, 1)
        n = n + 1
    Next
Next
}
```

Comment: Handle your Next statements properly. So `Next m` & `Next k`

Comment: Yes My Dear Friend. I Got it. For more control I have to use For k=14 to some x number. Thank You. And I Need Another Question Here. How to populate a listbox with two combobox selections in excel using VBA

Comment: Add another question detailing the next problem